# Substrings used for replacement

Tags: angularjs, string, substring, string-formatting, string-matching

This is more of a general question than anything.

I was wondering if there is a name for substrings used to inject values into a string.

Ex: If passed the string `Your name is @{user_name}`, then the substring `@{user_name}` would be replaced with a correct value.

Essentially I am wondering if that type of substring has a specific name/practice I could read up more about.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In es6 javascript there are [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that require special formatting. Otherwise inside regular quotes what you have are basically placeholders

Comment: @charlietfl That is exactly what I’m looking for. Thank you!